# Better way to find existence of arrays in list of arrays

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, arraylist, unique

I am a newbie to Python and trying out different ways to optimize and simplify my code.

I have a list of arrays(necessarily in this format) initially empty, which I need to update with arrays, making sure that duplicate entries are not added.

Right now I am doing it the following way, which is the only thing i tried out which works:

```
if len(where(((array(self.pop_next)-(self.pop[self.top_indv_indx[i]]))==0).sum(1)==len((self.pop[self.top_indv_indx[i]])))[0])<=0):
     self.pop_next.append(self.pop[self.top_indv_indx[i]])
```

where `self.pop_next` is my list of arrays and `self.pop[self.top_indv_indx[i]]` is the array to be added.

I know this Unpythonic and guess that there are much better simple ways to do the same.
Please Help

Comment: What is `where`? Are you using `numpy` arrays? Also it'd be nice if you could break the code into a couple of lines

Comment: Yes i am using numpy arrays.Right now i am implicitly trying to match the arrays using the where keyword.

Comment: If your trying to have a container of distinct objects maybe you should use `set` and your own `__cmp__` operation? What does your project do?

Comment: my project interfaces with a external simulator and therefore i need my data to be in array form.I have tried set but somehow it does'nt work directly unless followed by flattening (which gives me a set of numbers rather than vectors which i require)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try with `numpy.all(array1 == array2)` as condition for an individual array comparison.

**Extension in edit:**

To loop over the list, you may use the following:

```
if all((numpy.all(array_to_add != a) for a in array_list)):
    array_list.append(array_to_add)
```

This compares `array_to_add` to all elements of `array_list` by value. Note that `all` here is `__builtin__.all`, in contrast to `numpy.all`. If you did `from numpy import *` before, this will not work. Use `import numpy` instead and call functions by full name as in the example above.

If it is ok to compare by object (i.e. two arrays are only the same if the are the exact same object in memory), use the following simpler variant:

```
if array_to_add is not in array_list:
    array_list.append(array_to_add)
```

Comment: But i need to check the existence of an array within a list of arrays and i guess your code just helps me compare 2 arrays.

Comment: Does "existence of an array within a list of arrays" mean existence of exactly the same array object, or just existence of any array which happens to have the same lengths and values? The first one is very easy to check, see the `list.index` method, or just `object in list`.

Comment: do u mean a try except loop with the index checking,but wouldnt dat make my code less efficient as compared to my current one?

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit:** I see from your comment that you're using numpy arrays. I've never used numpy so I have no idea how they work with sets.

One option would be to use a `set`.  [Sets are like lists](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) but they are unordered and only allow each item to be added once:

```
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(1)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s.add(2)
>>> s
set([1, 2])
```

However, you'll run into problems if you try to add a `list` to a set:

```
>>> s.add(['my','list'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

An item [must be hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable) to add to `set`, and a `list` can't be hashable as it can't have  an unchanging hash value since it can be modified at any time by adding or removing values.

If you don't need the lists you are checking to be mutable you can convert them to tuples which are fixed and so hashable and so set-friendly:

```
>>> mylist = ['my','list']
>>> s = set()
>>> s.add(tuple(mylist))
>>> s.add(tuple(mylist))
>>> s
set([('my', 'list')])
```

Comment: Thanks Dave.I understand that this is simple but it also requires me to convert back the set of tuples to list of arrays form,as i need this form to run it on a parallel evaluator.

Comment: Depending on how many arrays you have and how long they are, the performance benefit of using a `set` may outweigh the cost of converting your arrays to/from tuples. You might need to run some timer tests using the `timeit` and/or `time` modules. [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html); [time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)